# OOP PHP Codeigniter Controller Hierarchy

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, form-submit, hierarchy

I'm having a litle problems with my concepts of OOP. I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have this class

```
class Application_controller extends CI_Controller{
     public function addItem(){
        "some code to add the item to the database (working)";
     }
}
```

And I have another class, both controllers:

```
require_once 'application_controller.php';
class Contact extends Application_controller{
     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct("variables needed");
     }
}
```

And in the View add of the contact I added the following action **contact/addItem**.

Ok, now here's what I know about OOP in general.

Isn't the method addItem supposed to be part of the Contact class because its extends Application_controller?

I'm asking because when I submit the form I get no action, and when I add the method addItem in the class Contact overriding the parent one it works.

Comment: I've never touched CI but your thinking in regards to OOP is indeed correct. You are however missing the `function` keyword from your `Contact` constructor

Comment: ehehe yes i am =) but only here :P on the real code i have it there =P i was probably hungry and eat it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to some similar question on the Codeigniter forums. It says this

> your ShopDownloads will inherit (methods,properties etc etc) from the Shop controller.  and as said in the video tutorial, u must inherit your class from the controller class so that it can inherit all the properties and methods codeigniter provides for u.

Sohaib,

The link for the post is http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102718/#518120

I don't know how but this is working today. It was probably the server. Just needed a restart.

Its Solved, just by start the server today and start developing LOL. Thanks for youre time guys.

Regards,

Elkas

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get no action is that codeigniter doesn't find a method addItem in your Contact class (update: this is probably due to the way CodeIgniter routing works). The solution would be to make addItem a generic method in a Model that stores data in a table, move it to a Model, and load the model in your controller.

Create application/models/writeModel.php

```
class writeModel extends CI_Model{
  function addItem(){
    // code here
  }
}
```

In your controller:

```
    class Contact extends Controller{
       function __controller(){
          parent::Controller();
          $this->load->model('writeModel');
       }

       function somefunction(){
          $this->writeModel->addItem(); // call the method here
       }
    }
```

Reference: [CodeIgniter Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Comment: Given that `Contact` extends `Application_controller`, it should indeed have a public `addItem` method, unless CI does something very strange with controller classes

Comment: I agree with @Phil but I don't see the justification for the downvote.  This does indeed sound weird but I wouldn't put it past CodeIgniter to do some funky reflection and not iterate up the inheritance chain.  Shivaas, if you want this answer accepted you should find a reference for the inheritance problem.

Comment: That would be something to do with how CodeIgniter routes to methods. My guess is it doesn't route to inherited public methods.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear - I'll try and find a reference to why codeigniter doesn't route to an inherited method.

Comment: Conceptually, what Elkas is trying to do is spot on, but when CodeIgniter loads the class Contact, PHP does not find 'Application_controller' class in contact.php, thus throwing a fatal error. My guess is Elkas has error reporting off in his PHP, and is hence seeing a blank response. To make this work, a require('...') statement in the Contact controller file would be required.

Comment: Sorry if i induce you in error mates. I have the require on top of the contact class. I'll change the question so more people won't be its that =) Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey guys, I found a similar question here, and according to it my code is correct. http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/102718/#518120
I'll try tomorrow to solve it and I'll tell as soon as i solve it. Probably its because I'm tired at the moment and and missing something so obvious i can't see it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (other then the several syntax errors in the OP) is likely to be that "Contact" can not extend "Application_controller" because it does not know it exists. If we setup a test like this:

**/controllers/Test.php**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

**/controllers/TestTwo.php**

```
require_once("Test.php");

class TestTwo extends Test    
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
        parent::index();
        echo ' and test two';
    }
}
```

We will get the desired output of "test and test two" by navigating to appurl/TestTwo/. This is because TestTwo knows of Test. Removing the require(); line from TestTwo.php will break the relation.

Removing the index() function from TestTwo will then result in only "test" being output by navigating to appurl/TestTwo/.

Comment: Hey mate. I have the code like that, i just didn't put here the obvious one =P sorry if i induce you in mistake. Indeed that works like that, but if the behavior of my addItem method is the same in every class controller i have whats the point putting it on the parent class if i have to override it on the children one and then call the parent method? It don't make sense to me and because of that i put it on the parent class, so i don't have to override it on the children ones. But i don't know the internal working in Codeigniter and if he accepts the inherits methods of parent controllers

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you don't want to create the child index() you don't have too. The parent will still fire.